# Python lists and def functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Hi i am new to python and i have a little problems with my code.

```
def Sumn(mylist):
    i = 0
    sum = 0    
    for i in mylist[1]:
        sum += mylist[i]
        return sum
    i+=1
```

```
import myFunctions

mylist = [6, 12, 645, 3, -8]
print(myFunctions.Sumn(mylist))
```

I was expecting that the numbers from the list will add and then the anwser will get printed

Comment: You're returning the sum after the first step.

Comment: Ok, I see you have posted some python code. Have you tried it? Does it produce any output? Are there any errors?

Comment: What went wrong. It looks to me like python would raise an error. If so, post that.

Answer (score 3):

Line by line comments:

```
def Sumn(mylist):
    i = 0       # this variable is unused
    sum = 0     # variable name overrides builtin 'sum' function
    for i in mylist[1]:    # this will error because mylist[1] is a single int
        sum += mylist[i]   # this only works if i is an index of mylist
        return sum         # returns in first iteration
    i+=1        # this variable still isn't used for anything
```

A correct implementation might look like:

```
def Sumn(mylist):
    total = 0
    for i in mylist:  # iterate over each value in mylist
        total += i    # add it to total
    return total      # return AFTER the entire loop is done
```

Of course in real life you would just call the builtin `sum` function:

```
mylist = [6, 12, 645, 3, -8]
print(sum(mylist))  # 658
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some errors in your code. In `for` loop you should use list `myList`, but you are using element at index 1 of the list `myList[1]`.

Also `for` loop iterates over elements not indices, so you should add `i` to the sum instead of `myList[i]`.

Finally, `return` statement should be after the loop, not inside it. The last line `i += 1` is after return so it does nothing (just remove it). Here is fixed code:

```
def Sumn(mylist):
    list_sum = 0    
    for i in mylist:
        list_sum += i
    
    return list_sum
```

Btw. don't use variables names that are builtins (`sum`).